# material angular 6.0.0 for production

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using angular material 5 currently but angular material 6 is having new features like tree. My question is about whether the angular material can be used for production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends , mostly a personal choice.Many use it in production. There may be changes to the library but if the component works for you then you should go for it. Even if the library changes you can reference the old version until you are ready to upgrade.